# What's a cleaner way to pass a function an array of values and then sort my object by those values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, lodash.js

The working code:

```
var dict = [
    {name: 'random234'}, 
    {name: 'random843'}
]       

function organizeObject(dict) {
    var resultArray = [];

    var x = _.find(dict, function(o) {
        return o.name === "random234";
    });
    if (x) resultArray.push(x);

    var y = _.find(dict, function(o) {
        return o.name === "random843";
    });
    if (y) resultArray.push(y);

    return resultArray;
}
```

I'm currently taking 'dict' in, finding name values using lodash's _.find method and if what I'm looking for exists - I'm pushing that to a new array to then return.

Is there a way to clean this up? One idea is to pass the function an array of name values I want the returned data set to by sorted by.

For instance:

```
 var sortByTheseValues = ['random843', 'random243'];
```

Ideally the original data set would be sorted by this array's values. jQuery is an option.

To clarify: 
I don't actually want to order by desc or asc, I want to order by a random array of values. If I specify ['random3', 'random2'] in an array, I want the object in the dictionary which corresponds to name: 'random3' to be first in the result.

Comment: I'm not sure about the lodash framework, etc., but it seems like your function just changes the order of things in the dictionary, based on the name: field. You also filter on a set of valid values. Is that all you're trying to do? Filter values and sort?

Comment: Lodash provides orderBy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928841/lodash-multi-column-sortby-descending#29082994

Comment: It's very hard to tell what is real and what is fabricated in this code excerpt. What do you mean by `random234` and `random843`? Are there only two special values? Does the `dict` only have those two items? If not, does the sort have to be a stable sort? Do you actually want the values in alphabetical order, or is the order purely arbitrary?

Comment: It would be much better if you posted your real code. Please see [ask].

Comment: I specifically call out what I'm looking for. It doesn't need more or more "real" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash provides `orderBy` (formerly `sortByOrder`), as mentioned in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928841/lodash-multi-column-sortby-descending#29082994)

Something like this might work:

```
var dict_sorted = _.orderBy(dict, ['name'], ['asc']);
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, you don't want lodash at all. You just want to sort an array by an arbitrary key. The key, in this case, is the order in which a value appears in another array of values provided by you.

`Array.sort()` takes a comparison function as its argument. I'd suggest the following:

1. Create a name -> integer mapping that will serve as the key. You will be passing an array, which is basically an integer->name mapping. So reverse it: name2index[name] = index (loop over all name/index pairs).
2. Provide a function to compare the two "keys":

   function(a,b){ return name2index[a] - name2index[b]; }
3. Figure out what should happen if a name is not present in the list you provided. Should unindexed values go to the top of the list? The bottom of the list? To /dev/null? Should the presence of such a value cause immediate failure?

Comment: I don't actually want to order by desc or asc, I want to order by a random array of values. If I specify ['random3', 'random2'] in an array, I want the object in the dictionary which corresponds to name: 'random3' to be first.

Comment: I'm marking yours as correct, although I implemented something different before seeing your response. I decided to have the function take in the dictionary and the array, loop over the array and per each iteration do a lodash _.find for that value in my dictionary. If it exists, push it to an array I'll then return. I figure I have to define the order I want it ordered by in my code somewhere anyways.